# Cannot understand this passage

Tags: grammar, words

> ランサーが深海からとってきた「ダイオウグソクムシ」を見てそのワキャワキャさにドン引きし、ランサーから「お前さんとこの竜牙兵もワキャワキャしてるじゃねえか」と言われて。

ワキャワキャさ:I can't find anything on this. 
I found that わきゃ means 私の, but I don't get the meaning of the sentence like this. 
It feels like being merry or overly joyful. 
竜牙兵:Are like living skeletons

Seeing the merryfulness of the Isopode that Lancer caught from the deep sea her mood was ruined and Lancer said (You too with those 竜牙兵, aren't overly cheerful?)

Or

Seeing how lancer was protective in regards to the isopode he caught from the deep sea she was drawn away and Lancer told her (Aren't you too overprotective with those 竜牙兵)

Could it mean over-protective?

The other sentence:

> 「ちょっとォ！！ GAIJINだからって馬鹿にしないでくれるゥ！？ SUSHIっていったらあれよ、豪華なSASHIMIがのっかってる見た目にも鮮やかな料理ってことぐらい知ってるわYO！！」

Wait!! could you not make fun of me just because I am a foreginer!? 
If you say Sushi, it's that! The appereance of a great Sashimi and a rich cooking. 
I know at least this!]

I don't get のっかってる, I read that it's 乗る with this meaning: （４）他人の考えなどを土台とする。のっかる。 but in this case the base is the Sashimi?

This is the whole context

If you need it:

> 「あれは我慢してるのよ必死に。今だから言うけど……」
>   『hollow』ドラマCD『怪物という名の食卓』にて。
>   ランサーが深海からとってきた「ダイオウグソクムシ」を見てそのワキャワキャさにドン引きし、ランサーから「お前さんとこの竜牙兵もワキャワキャしてるじゃねえか」と言われて。
>
> 「ちょっとォ！！ GAIJINだからって馬鹿にしないでくれるゥ！？ SUSHIっていったらあれよ、豪華なSASHIMIがのっかってる見た目にも鮮やかな料理ってことぐらい知ってるわYO！！」
>   同上。ド忘れしてしまった夫の好物と思われる料理を男サーヴァント衆に再現してもらい、その審査を務めることに。アーチャーが作った（おそらく正解と思われる）かっぱ巻きを見た反応。
>   この台詞のみエセ外国人風になっている。ちなみにランサーによると寿司の基本的な知識は聖杯からの知識に含まれているとのこと。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ワキャワキャ is not common at all, but I think it can be either of the followings:

- a variation of [わちゃわちゃ](http://jisho.org/word/%E3%82%8F%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83%E3%82%8F%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83), an uncommon mimetic word that describes noisy and cheerful people (eg, in a party). わいわい. がやがや.
- a variation of わきわき, a rare mimetic word that describes organic and unpredictable movements of multiple finger- or tentacle-like structures. うねうね. わさわさ. わらわら. You can see typical わきわき moves in [this page](http://gifmagazine.net/gifs/search_results?search%5Bword%5D=%E3%82%8F%E3%81%8D%E3%82%8F%E3%81%8D). And [here's a toy spider](https://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/B00QWSE992/) that's described as わきわき動く. I have no idea how to say this in English...

Since this ワキャワキャ is used for [ダイオウグソクムシ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%80%E3%82%A4%E3%82%AA%E3%82%A6%E3%82%B0%E3%82%BD%E3%82%AF%E3%83%A0%E3%82%B7), I guess it's used in the second sense. I personally haven't seen a skeleton described as ワキワキ/ワキャワキャ, but it's understandable (Fate's 竜牙兵 seems to be a hodgepodge of bone fragments).

---

> 豪華なSASHIMIがのっかってる見た目にも鮮やかな料理ってことぐらい

「豪華なSASHIMIがのっかってる」 and 「見た目にも鮮やかな」 independently modify 料理. 乗っかる is a colloquial synonym for 乗る. 見た目に is a set phrase that means "to the eye".

- 豪華なSASHIMIがのっかってる料理: a dish with gorgeous sashimi on it
- 見た目にも鮮やかな料理: a vivid-looking dish

Comment: I see, makes sense. 
Do you know a site where I could look up this onomathopeas and/or colloquialisms?  
Sometimes even if I google it I find that word but I can't find the meaning.

Comment: @Splikie No I don't know such a site. わきわき is already rare enough, and I don't think ワキャワキャ is something worth memorizing.