# what is the dakuten katakana character in the image?

Tags: katakana, kana

what is the dakuten katakana character in the image ?

Seem the image say `Xサ`?What is the X ?
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's [グサ](http://thejadednetwork.com/sfx/browse/gusa/), a common onomatopoeia for a sound of "stab". It also describes how someone's harsh word sticks into your heart. It's listed on jisho.org in the form [ぐさりと](http://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%90%E3%81%95%E3%82%8A%E3%81%A8).

It looks like ワ, too, but ワ does not take dakuten, as you know.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's true that ワ does not take dakuten, but I feel it's good to note that in colloquial contexts (especially in Anime/Manga, and particularly in mimetic or SFX words), pretty much any character can take on dakuten in order to give it a "rough"-sounding quality.

Comment: @RebeccaNelson Yes that's covered in [another question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32622/5010), but ワ゛ is extremely rare and ワ゛サ makes no sense to me anyway. (I know there is [わさわさ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/42934/5010))

Comment: Agreed, in this particular case it is very clearly a styled "ク".

Comment: ya know, some fonts are really difficult to decipher sometimes. I ran into a font with a chacter that looked like a mirror image TO, but come to find out is was squished U used to lengthen the vowel sound.