# What does ほわって mean?

Tags: expressions, onomatopoeia

> ほわぁ～って感じが好きです

A woman who's looking at a painting says that after saying that she likes it.

I've searched for ほわって, ほわっと, ほわっ, ほわ, ほわほわ on Jisho and Weblio (Japanese-English), but they're not there.

Comment: Are you familiar with 「って」 as a contraction of 「という」?

Comment: Are you sure you searched ほわほわ? It's definitely on Weblio and pretty much answers your question.

Comment: @Jimmy Could you give a link please? I don't see ほわほわ on Weblio either. Perhaps I'm looking in the wrong section.

Comment: Yeah, maybe you were looking in the wrong section. Here's the link: https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%BB%E3%82%8F%E3%81%BB%E3%82%8F

Comment: @istrasci Yes, of course.

Comment: @Jimmy It was not enough, I needed a further explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This site](https://goiryoku.com/onomatopoeia/howaltu/) gives the following meanings for ほわっ(と)

- 物や状態が軽く柔らかである様子。
- 表情や動作がゆったりとしている様子。
- 暖かな煙や湯気が立ち上る様子。

Basically, it expresses something being soft, mild, relaxing, warm. (Just searched on google, and found it's used in a [product name](https://www.pasconet.co.jp/products/3793/) for bread - being soft and relaxing is probably intended.)

Another related word (than the one linked in the comment) is [ほんわか](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%BB%E3%82%93%E3%82%8F%E3%81%8B/#jn-206535).

> ［副］心がなごんで、気持ちのよいさま。「—（と）して暖かい」「—ムード」

---

Though this may not be really helpful for learners, the meaning of onomatopoeia (at least many two-letter ones) depends on its consonants as mentioned in [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/89142/45489). In this case, it is ***h**o**w**a*. As such it has some similarity with another onomatopoeia ***h**u**w**a*=ふわっ/ふわふわ/ふわり/ふんわり, which shares with ほわっ the meaning of softness (ふわっ has no 'warm' sense).

Answer (score 1):

ほわ (or ほわほわ, ほわっと) is essentially an uncommon variant of ふわ (ふわふわ, ふわっと). ほわ sounds a bit cuter to me, but the difference is small. It's a very abstract word used to describe almost anything that is non-rigid,  elusive, girly, happy, warm, foggy, daydreamy, fluffy, relaxing or soft.

It's impossible to guess which part of the picture is being described as ほわぁ without actually seeing it, and it may still be challenging even when I see it. It may refer to the overall softness, happiness, or warmth of the picture, but it may be used to describe a super-abstract picture.

Comment: I agree with this distinction from sundowner’s answer: “ (ふわっ has no 'warm' sense).”, do you not get the same feeling?

Comment: @DariusJahandarie In this case, "warm" refers to psychological warmness, and it's difficult to strictly differentiate between "happy" and "warm". I don't think that the meaning of "warm" is more strongly expressed in either ふわ or ほわ. Still, I agree that ふわ tends to describe physical softness or fluffiness, while ほわ is more...abstract, so they may not be completely the same.